# Select rows other than first selected row in a table

Tags: sql-server-2012

My table looks like

```
 id     ledgerID    Amount  Debit or credit     TransactionType
 --------------------------------------------------------------
  1         1        500       dr               Sale1
  2         2        300       cr               sale1
  3         3        400       dr               sale1
  4         1        1000      dr               sale2
  5         2        200       cr               sale2
```

Now I like to select this table like

```
sno  LedgerID   Transaction     Dr        Cr
-----------------------------------------------
1    1          sale1          500
         2      300 cr
         3      400 dr
2    1          sale2         1000
         2      200 cr
```

How to do this?

Comment: Doesn't look like a table, what you want.

Comment: @ypercube edited, now see

Comment: You could do that (the presentation) in your application. Just use `ORDER BY TransactionType, ledgerID` in the query. It can be done in SQL sure, but why?

Comment: I edited once again... I just want it in sql only ...

Answer (score 1):

You can split the debit/credit columns using a CASE syntax:

```
(CASE WHEN [Debit or credit]='cr' THEN Amount END) AS cr,
(CASE WHEN [Debit or credit]='dr' THEN Amount END) AS dr
```

As for the "sno" column, I presume that the answer you're looking for is something like

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TransactionType) AS sno
```